# JPA Updating @ManyToOne of @OneToMany

Tags: jpa

Unable to update reference `permission` of `projectPermission` from `project`, Please find the below entities for your reference

**Project.java**

```
@OneToMany( cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, orphanRemoval = true,
                        mappedBy = "project", fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
private List<Projectpermission> permissions = new ArrayList<Projectpermission>();
```

**ProjectPermission.java**

```
@ManyToOne
@Column( nullable = false )
private Permission permission;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn( name = "PPM_PRJ_ID", nullable = false )
private Project           project;
```

**`JSON` object to update**

```
{
    "projectDescription": "Jeta description",
    "permissions": [{
        "projectPermissionId": 2551,
        "person": "XXX",
        "permission": {
            "permissionName": "read",
            "permissionId": 2
        }
    } ],
    "projectName": "Jeta",
    "projectId": 2
}
```

On updating `project`, the `projectPermission` should get updated, But getting null as a response to `projectPermission` array after successful update.

**Response after update**

```
{
    "projectDescription": "Jeta description",
    "permissions": [],
    "projectName": "Jeta",
    "projectId": 2
}
```

Comment: mappedBy should match the `permission`. Also, you must set the `permission` field for each `Projectpermission`s inside `permissions` before saving.

Comment: actually, project permission has got project attribute with it, so have mapped by `mappedBy = project` in `project.java`, Permission has already been set in each project permission before sent for saving.

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino as the projectpermission is mapped by project,  the projectpermission with the mapped project to be saved first in the projectpermission table first and later the project should get saved with the reference, everything should happen within one transaction while saving the project object, Any idea on this. I have checked the permission, it is available with the projectpermission by default.

Comment: Updated ProjectPermission by setting the project - backreference on projectPermission before saving. works well!

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `project` backreference into the `projectpermission` made the update work, all referred `projectpermission` has also been saved along with project and hence the referred `permission` on `projectpermission`. Please find the below snippet for reference,

```
    List< Projectpermission > permissions = project.getPermissions();
    ArrayList< Projectpermission > updatedProjectPermissionsList = new ArrayList< Projectpermission >();
    for ( Projectpermission projectPermissions : permissions ) {
        projectPermissions.setProject( project ); // <- solution setting the project backreference to the individual permission entity makes it work
        updatedProjectPermissionsList.add( projectPermissions );
    }
    project.getPermissions().addAll( updatedProjectPermissionsList );
    Project updateProject = projectRepositoryBeanLocal.updateProject( project );
```